# Generic ManyToMany for multiple inherited models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, many-to-many

First of all, the following code is not an example of best practices in DB modelling and I know it, unfortunately, this is already made and it's what it is. Remodelling everything is just not an option.

I have the following models:

```
models.py

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    ...


class AbstractSite(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Site(AbstractSite):
    ...

class Banner(Site):
    data = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel, blank=True)
```

The issue is, this many-to-many is supposed to be present both in the Site and the Banner models.

I've tried to specify it in the Abstract Model, and it created a site_data table, but data saved in the Banner model was also populating this table, instead of populating a banner_data as I was expecting.

The easiest way is to create a new field in the Site model, named differently from the data field in the Banner model, but this doesn't seem to be correct, since any new child model would need a new table being declared. I was expecting to find a way to dynamically allocate this in the DB.

Is there a way to create a dynamic `through` parameter that follows the class child class name?

Comment: Haven't tested this, but if you want the through table dynamically created for the children, you'll have to declare the m2m field on the abstract model, and get rid of the first non-child concrete class which is `Site` (or make `Site` abstract as well)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be correct. Unfortunately, I can't get rid of the Site model. I'll try instead to make another abstract class with Site properties and pass it as the parent of the Site and Banner model. Thank you